# How can I visible HTML markup component in Timer method in Class

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, jboss, wicket

On Timer event I want to make visible the component again. Is there any different method to achieve this task? I attached the snipet belove.

HTML markup: In this file I Create the alert bar

```
  <div Class="row" wicket:id="alert_app" >
      <div  class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="top: 2%; left: 50%; position: absolute;">
      <a href="#" wicket:id="alert" style="color:red"  >Alert - Match Found</a>

     </div>
    </div>
```

Java Class: I had instantiate the WebMarkupContainer and make invisible at initial stage, after the 5 second alert bar will appears(it is my plan) for that I use Timer and I stuck in timer event.

```
 WebMarkupContainer informationBox = new WebMarkupContainer("alert_app");
     add(informationBox);

        final AjaxLink saveProfile = new AjaxLink("alert") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

            this.setResponsePage(ABC.class);
        }

    };

    informationBox.add(saveProfile);
    informationBox.setVisible(false);  

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            informationBox.setVisibilityAllowed(true);

            informationBox.setVisible(true);   // I got error in this line

        }
    }, 5000);
```

Errors:

```
   12:37:04,735 INFO  
  [org.apache.wicket.response.filter.AjaxServerAndClientTimeFilter] (http-
   localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4) 1ms server time taken for request 
wicket/bookmarkable/xyz.abc.vbn.class?
4&username=user+name response size: 9386
12:37:09,736 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-3) Exception in thread "Timer-3" 
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: No RequestCycle is currently set!

12:37:09,736 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-3)   at 
org.apache.wicket.Component.getRequest(Component.java:1791)

12:37:09,736 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-3)   at 
org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.dirty(WebPage.java:334)

12:37:09,736 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-3)   at 
org.apache.wicket.Page.dirty(Page.java:248)

12:37:09,736 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-3)   at 
org.apache.wicket.Page.componentStateChanging(Page.java:937)

12:37:09,736 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-3)   at 
org.apache.wicket.Component.addStateChange(Component.java:3512)

12:37:09,736 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-3)   at 
org.apache.wicket.Component.setVisible(Component.java:3195)


 12:37:09,736 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-3)  at 
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)

 12:37:09,736 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-3)  at 
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot just use `java.util.Timer`. It starts a new Thread that is not HTTP worker thread, so WicketFilter has no chance to setup the ThreadLocal's (Application, Session and RequestCysle).

You have to use `org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior` instead.
It will trigger a new Ajax request after the given duration and everything will work as expected!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I don't see in the code

```
informationBox.setOutputMarkupId(true);
informationBox.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I put my answer over here so it could help helpful for viewers , thanks @Alexei and @martin, You both guy's answer is very helpful.

```
 WebMarkupContainer informationBox = new WebMarkupContainer("alert_app");
 informationBox.add(new AjaxLink("alert1"){

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.setResponsePage(ABC.class);
        } });

    add(informationBox);
    informationBox.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    informationBox.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);


   informationBox.setVisible(false);

   this.add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(5))
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target)
        {
            target.add(informationBox.setVisible(true));
            System.out.println("on timer");

            stop(target);
        }
    });
```